# Is the given discrete random vector independent?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification, independence

> A random vector $(X,Y)$ has PMF given by $p(1,-1) = p(-1,1) = 1/2$. Are $X,Y$ independent?

I think they are dependent because $p(X=1)=p(Y= -1)= 1/2$ and $p(X=1,Y= -1)\ne p(X=1)*p(Y= -1)$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct

Comment: @ShubhamJohri If I have X^2 and Y^2 are they dependent or independent?

Comment: $X^2=1,Y^2=1,p(X^2=1,Y^2=1)=1=p(X^2=1)\times p(Y^2=1)$. So they are independent.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri thankyou for clarification

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy can you post the correct one?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy How come? We are talking about $X^2,Y^2$, not $X,Y$

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Apologies. Your comments are correct. I am not familiar with the notation $!=$ for $\neq $.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Hmm, true this is not really used in mathematics. It comes from computer programming languages and probably the OP used it because he didn't have the $\ne$ symbol on keyboard

Comment: @hrithikmahesh Accept Kavi sir's answer if it is satisfactory to you by pressing the tick-mark button next to it. And welcome to this website! Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your equations in future (I had done it for you this time.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not independent. $X$ and $Y$ take the values $+1$ and $-1$. Note that $p(1,1)+p(-1,-1)+p(1,-1)+p(-1,1)=1$. Since $p(1,-1)+p(-1,1)=\frac 1 2+\frac 1  2 =1$ we get $p(1,1)=p(-1,-1)=0$. Now consider $p(1,1)=0$ This is not equal to $P(X=1)P(Y=1)$. In fact $P(X=1)=p(1,1)+p(1,-1)=\frac 1 2$ and $P(Y=1)=p(1,1)+p(-1,1)=\frac 1 2$ so $P(X=1)P(Y=1)=\frac 1 4$.

$X^{2}$ and $Y^{2}$ are independent since they are both equal to $1$ almost surely.